# PHP get arrayfrequency using for loop

Tags: php, loops

I have this in my code to get the frequencies of an array.

```
$arr = array(10, 9, 23, 7, 40, 43, 7, 5, 10, 7);
$frq = array_count_values($arr);
foreach($frq as $key => $values){ print $key . " = " . $values . "<br>";}
```

output:

```
5 = 1
7 = 3
9 = 1
10 = 2
23 = 1
40 = 1
43 = 1
```

Now is there a way to solve this using `for` loop only - i.e. without using `array_count_values()` function? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty Unclear. What you want to achieve over here.

Comment: Hi @Uchiha as you can see the sample output from my code to calculate the number of occurence, what i want is how can i able to do that without using array_count_values function just for loop only..thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$arr = array(10, 9, 23, 7, 40, 43, 7, 5, 10, 7);
$frq= array();
foreach($arr as $a) {
   if(array_key_exists($a, $frq)) {
       $frq[$a] += 1; 
   }
   else
   {
       $frq[$a] = 1;
   }
}
foreach($frq as $key => $values){ 
    print $key . " = " . $values . "<br>";
}
```

Without any function -

```
foreach($arr as $a) {
   $frq[$a] = (!empty($frq[$a])) ? ($frq[$a] + 1) : 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks @b0s3..but i just want a for loop only..no other function like array_key_exists.just for loop..thanks..

Comment: Then you have to use more loops. BTW why not using those functions??

Comment: because there is no function like array_key_exists in C or javascript.

Comment: So what? Why are you comparing them?

Comment: @b0s3 you just update your answer and I'll remove mine

Comment: I am not sure but that may raise error in older versions. I am updating it with a check.

Comment: Yep it'll you simply used ternary not a bad choice +1

Answer (score 0):

Do it as below -

```
<?php
$arr = array(10, 9, 23, 7, 40, 43, 7, 5, 10, 7);
$frq= array();
foreach($arr as $value)
{
  $frq[$value]=isset($frq[$value])?$frq[$value]+1:1;
}
print_r($frq);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [10] => 2 [9] => 1 [23] => 1 [7] => 3 [40] => 1 [43] => 1 [5] => 1 )
```